# progressBar for large function

Tags: apache-flex

I have a function that when called takes about 10 seconds to run. I’d like to add a simple progress bar to show the user something is happening but the progressBar doesn’t run until the function is finished

```
btn.addEventListener("click",bigFunction);

private function bigFunction(event:Event):void{
     var progress:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
     progress.indeterminate = true;
     progress.validateNow();
     mainPanel.addChild(progress)

    // do massive loop

}
```

Is there a way to force the progress bar to run before the rest of the function is completed. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The execution model for Flex/Actionscript is single threaded. You have to take some tricky approach to handle this.

http://blogs.infosupport.com/flex-4-a-multi-threading-solution/

Take a look at this example.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible. Why? because **Flash** (Flex does nothing) is single-threaded, a 10 second function will just cause the display (and hence the browser, if you are displaying it in a browser) to freeze. Even so, you can try the following:

Force a refresh on the progressbar using

```
progress.invalidateDisplayList();
```

after the `addChild`

This will add the progressbar to the redraw list

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not force the player to redraw. Invalidating just tells the player, that this component needs to be redrawn. But it won't be redrawn, until the code phase does its work.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash, to repaint anything, you need a new frame to be processed by swf (Event.ENTER_FRAME). Your 10-second function should be split to shorter calls, or it indeed just hangs the Flash player. If you're processing something large, do it in limited portions. You can use `getTimer()` function to control portion size.